# RawKeyboardListener not working on Flutter for Windows

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I'm currently working on a Flutter app for Windows, and I try to detect keyboard inputs (like space, arrows, enter...).

For that purpose, I use `RawKeyboardListener` in my widget:

```
class _WaveformWidgetState extends State<WaveformWidget>
{

  FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return RawKeyboardListener(
      autofocus: true,
      focusNode: _focusNode,
      onKey: (event) {
        if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter))
        {
          print("value : enter");
        }
      },
      child: Container(...),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is: that widget is inside another widget, which contains a form, with multiple `TextFormFields`, buttons and so on.

And because of that, it seems that the `TextFormFields` somehow keep the focus and prevent my `RawKeyboardListener` from working.

So I tried by adding `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);` inside the `build()` method of that widget, but now my `TextFormFields` always loose focus when I click on them. Pretty sure it's a focus related problem, but I don't know how to deal with it.

So how can I properly listen to raw keyboard events in my current widget without compromising my form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

OK so I found 2 solutions to my problem:

With `RawKeyboardListener`:

1. Add a click listener in the widget, and when clicked, call: `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);`
2. In the `onKey` callback of `RawKeyboardListener`, also add: `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);`

With `FocusNode` (thanks to [that link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67363189/3527024)):

```
class _WaveformWidgetState extends State<WaveformWidget>
{
  FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  late FocusAttachment _focusAttachment;
  
  @override
  void initState()
  {
    super.initState();
    _focusAttachment = _focusNode.attach(context, onKeyEvent: (node, event) {
      if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.enter)
      {
        print("value : enter");
      }
      return KeyEventResult.handled;
    });
    _focusNode.requestFocus();
  }

  @override
  void dispose()
  {
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    _focusAttachment.reparent();
    return Container(...);
  }
}
```

I personally prefer the second solution, since it seems to work very well, and also allows you to easily handle event like shift+click (check [that link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67363189/3527024) again for more info on that).

Comment: you can use this method too:
```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    _focusAttachment.reparent();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```